# Javascript chance with decimals

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

Below, I have `gold` as a variable and `chance` as a variable. This applies to each set. If you add up all the `chance` variables, you will get 100. I am try to use the `chance` variables to calculate a change. (e.g. 1% chance that `gold` will be `l50`). I have tried `Math.random()`, `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)`, and countless others. How to can I use the items in this JSON table to calculate chance?

```json
[
  { "gold": "l50"    , "chance": 1    },
  { "gold": "swap"   , "chance": 2    },
  { "gold": "0"      , "chance": 2    },
  { "gold": "l25"    , "chance": 3    },
  { "gold": "t10"    , "chance": 4    },
  { "gold": "t25"    , "chance": 4    },
  { "gold": "triple" , "chance": 4    },
  { "gold": 10       , "chance": 5    },
  { "gold": 100      , "chance": 7.5  },
  { "gold": "double" , "chance": 9    },
  { "gold": 20       , "chance": 12.5 },
  { "gold": 50       , "chance": 13.5 },
  { "gold": 40       , "chance": 15   },
  { "gold": 30       , "chance": 17.5 }
]
```

EDIT:
The JSON above is just for show, the variables are not going to be in JSON format. On a second note, an example would be that someone would have 1% chance of getting `l50` or in other terms `lose 50`. They would also have a 15% chance of instead getting `30` gold.

Comment: `Math.random * 100` won’t work: you can’t multiply a function by a number.

Comment: `Math.random() < chance / 100` Is how you figure out if if this chance occurred.

Comment: *1% chance that gold will be l50* eh?

Comment: What do you mean with _"How to can I use the items in this JSON table to calculate chance?"_ What do you want to calculate? Can you give an example? Rounding could change the sum: e.g. 33.3 + 33.3 + 33.4 = 100 but Math.floor(33.3) + Math.floor(33.3) + Math.floor(33.4) = 33 + 33 + 33 = 99

Comment: @ThomasSablik The JSON table is just for example, I actual data is going to be in variable format. What I want is to have the random chance on the increase in the player's score. And the chance of getting each increase is in the `chance` variable.

Comment: Calculate the sum of all chances (in your case 100). Create a random value `x` in the range (0, sum]. If `x <= 1` choose `"gold": "l50"`, else if `x <= 3` choose `"gold": "swap"`, else if `x <= 5` choose `"gold": "0"`, else if `x <= 8` choose `"gold": "125"`, ...

Comment: Cool! Thank will work. I think something else might work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have floating values for your chances, you can double their values to a whole number. This makes the total chance 200. Now you can multiply a random value by 200 to get a range value. You can then return an index for that range. Once you have an index, you can look-up the corresponding probability value.

Larger indices will correspond to more-probable chances.

**Edit:** I modified this to keep track of the index frequency. At the very end of the log, you can see how the actual frequency compares to the chance. The results will be very close. More iterations, the closer the values.

**Edit 2:** Check the bottom of this response, for a more flexible function that loops-through pivot values (min/max thresholds) and determines the index. This eliminates the need for generating if-conditions.

```js
const probability = [
  { "gold": "l50"    , "chance":  1   }, //  1.0 * 2 =  2 | [   0,   1 ]
  { "gold": "swap"   , "chance":  2   }, //  2.0 * 2 =  4 | [   2,   5 ]
  { "gold": "0"      , "chance":  2   }, //  2.0 * 2 =  4 | [   6,   9 ]
  { "gold": "l25"    , "chance":  3   }, //  3.0 * 2 =  6 | [  10,  15 ]
  { "gold": "t10"    , "chance":  4   }, //  4.0 * 2 =  8 | [  16,  23 ]
  { "gold": "t25"    , "chance":  4   }, //  4.0 * 2 =  8 | [  24,  31 ]
  { "gold": "triple" , "chance":  4   }, //  4.0 * 2 =  8 | [  32,  39 ]
  { "gold": 10       , "chance":  5   }, //  5.0 * 2 = 10 | [  40,  49 ]
  { "gold": 100      , "chance":  7.5 }, //  7.5 * 2 = 15 | [  50,  64 ]
  { "gold": "double" , "chance":  9   }, //  9.0 * 2 = 18 | [  65,  82 ]
  { "gold": 20       , "chance": 12.5 }, // 12.5 * 2 = 25 | [  83, 107 ]
  { "gold": 50       , "chance": 13.5 }, // 13.5 * 2 = 27 | [ 108, 134 ]
  { "gold": 40       , "chance": 15   }, // 15.0 * 2 = 30 | [ 135, 164 ]
  { "gold": 30       , "chance": 17.5 }  // 17.5 * 2 = 35 | [ 165, 199 ]
];

const lookupIndex = (n) => {
  if (n >=   0 && n <   2) return  0;
  if (n >=   2 && n <   6) return  1;
  if (n >=   6 && n <  10) return  2;
  if (n >=  10 && n <  16) return  3;
  if (n >=  16 && n <  24) return  4;
  if (n >=  24 && n <  32) return  5;
  if (n >=  32 && n <  40) return  6;
  if (n >=  40 && n <  50) return  7;
  if (n >=  50 && n <  65) return  8;
  if (n >=  65 && n <  83) return  9;
  if (n >=  83 && n < 108) return 10;
  if (n >= 108 && n < 135) return 11;
  if (n >= 135 && n < 165) return 12;
  if (n >= 165 && n < 200) return 13;
};

const
  roll = () => lookupIndex(Math.floor(Math.random() * 200)),
  iterations = 1000,
  frequency = probability.map(() => 0);

for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  const rollIndex = roll();
  frequency[rollIndex]++;
  console.log(rollIndex, JSON.stringify(probability[rollIndex]));
}

const results = frequency.map((value, index) => ({
  actual: Math.floor((value / iterations) * 100),
  expected: probability[index].chance
}));

console.log('>> RESULTS');
results.forEach(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

### Generate index lookup conditions

Here is the logic to generate the if-statements I declared in the example above.

```js
const probability = [
  { "gold": "l50"    , "chance":  1   }, //  1.0 * 2 =  2 | [   0,   1 ]
  { "gold": "swap"   , "chance":  2   }, //  2.0 * 2 =  4 | [   2,   5 ]
  { "gold": "0"      , "chance":  2   }, //  2.0 * 2 =  4 | [   6,   9 ]
  { "gold": "l25"    , "chance":  3   }, //  3.0 * 2 =  6 | [  10,  15 ]
  { "gold": "t10"    , "chance":  4   }, //  4.0 * 2 =  8 | [  16,  23 ]
  { "gold": "t25"    , "chance":  4   }, //  4.0 * 2 =  8 | [  24,  31 ]
  { "gold": "triple" , "chance":  4   }, //  4.0 * 2 =  8 | [  32,  39 ]
  { "gold": 10       , "chance":  5   }, //  5.0 * 2 = 10 | [  40,  49 ]
  { "gold": 100      , "chance":  7.5 }, //  7.5 * 2 = 15 | [  50,  64 ]
  { "gold": "double" , "chance":  9   }, //  9.0 * 2 = 18 | [  65,  82 ]
  { "gold": 20       , "chance": 12.5 }, // 12.5 * 2 = 25 | [  83, 107 ]
  { "gold": 50       , "chance": 13.5 }, // 13.5 * 2 = 27 | [ 108, 134 ]
  { "gold": 40       , "chance": 15   }, // 15.0 * 2 = 30 | [ 135, 164 ]
  { "gold": 30       , "chance": 17.5 }  // 17.5 * 2 = 35 | [ 165, 199 ]
];

const generateLookupConditions = (chances, scale=1, precision=0) =>
  (offset => chances
    .reduce((acc, curr, index, all) =>
      ((count, last) =>
        [ ...acc, { start: last, end: last + count } ])
      (curr * scale, index > 0 ? acc[index - 1].end : 0), [])
    .map((range, index) =>
      ((min, max, i) => `if (n >= ${min} && n < ${max}) return ${i};`)
      (
        ('' + range.start.toFixed(precision)).padStart(3 + offset + !!(scale > 1), ' '),
        ('' + range.end.toFixed(precision)).padStart(4 + offset, ' '),
        ('' + index).padStart(2, ' ')
      ))
    .join('\n'))
  (precision === 0 ? -1 : precision);

const s2p0 = generateLookupConditions(probability.map(p => p.chance), 2);
const s1p1 = generateLookupConditions(probability.map(p => p.chance), 1, 1);
const s1p0 = generateLookupConditions(probability.map(p => p.chance), 1);

console.log(`Scale = 2, Precision = 0\n${'='.repeat(25)}\n${s2p0}`);
console.log(`Scale = 1, Precision = 1\n${'='.repeat(25)}\n${s1p1}`);
console.log(`Scale = 1, Precision = 0\n${'='.repeat(25)}\n${s1p0}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Using pivots

Alternatively, instead of iterating through n-number of if-conditions, you can generate an array of pivots. You can then pass the random value into an unpivot function to determine the index in your probability table.

```js
const probability = [
  { "gold": "l50"    , "chance":  1   }, //  1.0 * 2 =  2 | [   0,   1 ]
  { "gold": "swap"   , "chance":  2   }, //  2.0 * 2 =  4 | [   2,   5 ]
  { "gold": "0"      , "chance":  2   }, //  2.0 * 2 =  4 | [   6,   9 ]
  { "gold": "l25"    , "chance":  3   }, //  3.0 * 2 =  6 | [  10,  15 ]
  { "gold": "t10"    , "chance":  4   }, //  4.0 * 2 =  8 | [  16,  23 ]
  { "gold": "t25"    , "chance":  4   }, //  4.0 * 2 =  8 | [  24,  31 ]
  { "gold": "triple" , "chance":  4   }, //  4.0 * 2 =  8 | [  32,  39 ]
  { "gold": 10       , "chance":  5   }, //  5.0 * 2 = 10 | [  40,  49 ]
  { "gold": 100      , "chance":  7.5 }, //  7.5 * 2 = 15 | [  50,  64 ]
  { "gold": "double" , "chance":  9   }, //  9.0 * 2 = 18 | [  65,  82 ]
  { "gold": 20       , "chance": 12.5 }, // 12.5 * 2 = 25 | [  83, 107 ]
  { "gold": 50       , "chance": 13.5 }, // 13.5 * 2 = 27 | [ 108, 134 ]
  { "gold": 40       , "chance": 15   }, // 15.0 * 2 = 30 | [ 135, 164 ]
  { "gold": 30       , "chance": 17.5 }  // 17.5 * 2 = 35 | [ 165, 199 ]
];

const generatePivots = (chances, scale=1) => chances
  .reduce((acc, curr, index, all) =>
    ((count, last) => [ ...acc, last + count ])
    (curr * scale, index > 0 ? acc[index - 1] : 0), [])
  .map((range, index) => range);

const unpivot = (pivots, value) =>
  pivots.findIndex((pivot, index) =>
    ((prev, curr) => value >= prev && value < curr)
    (index > 0 ? pivots[index - 1] : 0, pivots[index]));

const randomChoiceIndex = (pivots, scale=1) =>
  unpivot(pivots, Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 * scale)));

const
  scale = 2,
  pivots = generatePivots(probability.map(p => p.chance), scale),
  roll = () => randomChoiceIndex(pivots, scale),
  iterations = 1000,
  frequency = probability.map(() => 0);

for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  const rollIndex = roll();
  frequency[rollIndex]++;
}

const results = frequency.map((value, index) => ({
  actual: Math.floor((value / iterations) * 100),
  expected: probability[index].chance
}));

console.log('>> PIVOTS');
console.log(JSON.stringify(pivots));
console.log('>> RESULTS');
results.forEach(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Normalized pivots without scaling

Just stick with floating-point values within the range `[0.0, 1.0)` for your `chance` values. This greatly simplifies the logic.

```js
const probability = [
  { "gold": "l50"    , "chance": 0.010 },
  { "gold": "swap"   , "chance": 0.020 },
  { "gold": "0"      , "chance": 0.020 },
  { "gold": "l25"    , "chance": 0.030 },
  { "gold": "t10"    , "chance": 0.040 },
  { "gold": "t25"    , "chance": 0.040 },
  { "gold": "triple" , "chance": 0.040 },
  { "gold": 10       , "chance": 0.050 },
  { "gold": 100      , "chance": 0.075 },
  { "gold": "double" , "chance": 0.090 },
  { "gold": 20       , "chance": 0.125 },
  { "gold": 50       , "chance": 0.135 },
  { "gold": 40       , "chance": 0.150 },
  { "gold": 30       , "chance": 0.175 } 
];

const generatePivots = (chances) => chances
  .reduce((acc, curr, index, all) =>
    (last => [ ...acc, curr + last ])
    (acc[index - 1] ?? 0), [])
  .map((range, index) => range);

const unpivot = (pivots, value) =>
  pivots.findIndex((pivot, index) =>
    ((prev, curr) => value >= prev && value < curr)
    (index > 0 ? pivots[index - 1] : 0, pivots[index]));

const
  randomPivotIndex = pivots => unpivot(pivots, Math.random()),
  pivots = generatePivots(probability.map(p => p.chance)),
  roll = () => randomPivotIndex(pivots),
  iterations = 1000,
  frequency = probability.map(() => 0);

for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) frequency[roll()]++;

const formatPercentage = percentage => `${(percentage * 100).toFixed(1)}%`;

const results = frequency.map((value, index) => ({
  actual   : formatPercentage(value / iterations),
  expected : formatPercentage(probability[index].chance)
}));

console.log('>> PIVOTS');
console.log(`[${pivots.map(v => v.toFixed(3)).join(',')}]`);
console.log('>> RESULTS');
results.forEach(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Calculate the sum of all chances (in your case 100).
2. Create a random value `x` in the range [0, sum), e.g. with `Math.random() * sum`
3. If `x < 1` choose `"gold": "l50"`,

   else if `x < 3` choose `"gold": "swap"`,

   else if `x < 5` choose `"gold": "0"`,

   else if `x < 8` choose `"gold": "125"`,

   else if `x < 12` choose `"gold": "t10"`,

   else if `x < 16` choose `"gold": "t25"`,

   else if `x < 20` choose `"gold": "triple"`,

   else if `x < 25` choose `"gold": "10"`,

   else if `x < 32.5` choose `"gold": "100"`,

   else if `x < 41.5` choose `"gold": "double"`,

   else if `x < 54` choose `"gold": "20"`,

   else if `x < 67.5` choose `"gold": "50"`,

   else if `x < 82.5` choose `"gold": "40"`,

   else choose `"gold": "30"`

Of course you don't need to write so many if conditions. You can use a loop algorithm like

```
x = random() * 100
sum = 0
row = 0
while x > sum
    sum += rows[row].chance
    ++row
return rows[row].gold
```